# How to create executable with Python 3.5 on Windows?

Tags: python, eclipse, py2exe, python-3.5

I'm starting with Python so I downloaded the 3.5 version on my Windows 7 (64), and developped a small app in Eclipse Luna (4.4.1) with PyDev and the Tkinter library. It has only 4 modules and a text file.

I'd like to know how I could export an executable version of my project, like when you do *File*>*Export*>*Runnable Jar File* with a Java project. Is there a way to do this in Eclipse for Python projects ?

I have already tried tools like **py2exe** or **cx_Freeze**, but they tell me they have to be used respectively with Python 2.7 and 3.4... Does there exists some piece of software that could do the same for Python 3.5 ?

Thank you very much for any piece of help you could bring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) (version 3.2) works for Python 3.5, according to their website.

Comment: Although I have not used it for Python 3.5, I use this tool with Python 2.7 with success.

Comment: I'm going to test this right away, I didn't know this tool

Comment: Well I get the "SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to `print`" at install, so I guess I'll have to download Python 2.7 anyway... or rewrite all the `print` calls in PyInstaller ! I'll check if there is an installer for Python 3.x especially.